# PyCrypto and GMP library not found error [Mac OS 10.6.3]

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to install `pycrypto-2.1.0` but attempt to do with `'python setup.py build'` elicits:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
```

I installed GMP (gmp-4.3.2) and it's in: `/usr/local/lib`

How do I get python/pycrypto to recognize that GMP is already present on my system?

Mac OS: 10.6.3
Python version: 2.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib /usr/lib/libgmp.dylib
```

Comment: For users using MacPorts this would be in /opt/local/lib :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at setup.py for pycrypto, it only searches for GMP in `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.  To fix this, either change setup.py to also search `/usr/local/lib` by adding it to the list on line 155 (recommended), or reinstall GMP into `/lib` or `/usr/lib` (not recommended but would work).

You may also need to add `self.__add_compiler_option('-I/usr/local/include'); self.__add_compiler_option('-L/usr/local/lib')` in order for the compiler to find the proper include files and static libraries if it doesn't include those paths by default.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem but libgmp located in /usr/lib, and /usr/local/lib is empty.
Problem solved by installing gmp-devel and python-devel packages.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, you should put more log lines. I had that error, but my problem was that I didn't install the python-dev package in my Ubuntu Karmic.