# python pycrypto installation error

Tags: python, pycrypto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PyCrypto and GMP library not found error [Mac OS 10.6.3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709661/pycrypto-and-gmp-library-not-found-error-mac-os-10-6-3)

I'm trying to install pycrypto on ubuntu, but it throws error

```
hom@PC71:~/Desktop/pycrypto-2.3$ sudo python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/MD2.o
src/MD2.c:31: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed python-dev tools already.

Answer (score 42):

You are missing the Python development libraries. (Try `apt-get install python-dev`.)

However, unless you have a valid reason to compile pycrypto yourself, just install it via (I think) `apt-get install python-crypto`.

Comment: works on linux: if you have installed GMP but don't have the python dev libraries youll need to get them before you install pycrypto

Comment: "apt-get install python-crypto" worked for me on my Raspberry Pi, thank you!

Comment: This solved an issue I had in the course of installing the dependencies necessary for upgrading Ansible via pip: `sudo pip install ansible --upgrade` (one of which was pycrypto)

Comment: For others that come by here trying to install on python3, you need `apt-get install python3-dev`